# Fourier series problems

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I've got an "interesting" problem. I've gotten a way through it, but I'd like someone to look if what I've done so far is correct, and what to do next.

We've got a function that is $0$ on the interval $[-\pi,0]$, and $\sin(x)$ on $[0,\pi]$.

I've calculated the Fourier coefficients to be 
$$
-\frac{(-1)^{n}}{\pi n^{2}-\pi},
$$

and the series being

$$
1/\pi + \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}-\frac{(-1)^{n}}{\pi n^{2}-\pi} e^{inx}.
$$

However, the next part of the assignment is to rewrite this series as

$$
1/\pi + \frac{1}{2} \sin(x) 
-\frac{2}{\pi} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4n^{2}-1} \cos(2nx),
$$

and this is giving me some trouble. I'm thinking I'm supposed to use Euler's theorem to split up the exponential, and then move $\frac{2}{\pi}$ outside of the sum, but however I try, I can't quite make it all add up. Do I have an error in my earlier calculations, or am I just going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Yes, something in your calculation went wrong for $n=1$ and $n=-1$. Which you can see by considering that in these cases you would divide by zero.

Comment: So do I need to recalculate the Fourier integral for -1 and 1? Or does a general term for every coefficient exist?

Comment: Calculating the integrals for those coefficients, they cancel each other out, so while of course important to mention, it wasn't the issue. Thanks for spotting it, though!

Comment: No, you get a different nature of the integrals. Which you can detect by testing for division by zero during integration. Also, your original formula is somewhat off, you need to include both endpoints of the integration interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
2\pi c_n&=\int_0^\pi\sin(x)e^{-inx}\,dx=\int_0^\pi\frac1{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})e^{-inx}\,dx\\
4\pi ic_n&=\int_0^\pi e^{-i(n-1)x}\,dx-\int_0^\pi e^{-i(n+1)x}\,dx\\
&=\begin{cases}
\pi&\text{for }n=1\\
-\pi&\text{for }n=-1\\
\frac{i}{n-1}(e^{i(n-1)\pi}-1)-\frac{i}{n+1}(e^{i(n+1)\pi}-1)&\text{else}
\end{cases}\\[1em]
\implies
c_n&=\begin{cases}
\pm\frac1{4i}&\text{for }n=\pm 1\\
0&\text{for all other odd }n\\
-\frac{1}{\pi(n^2-1)}\text{for even }n.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Which is slightly, but not totally, different from your result.

Comment: I tried to calculate some of this again, but I get  $c_{1} = -\frac{i}{4}$ in Mathcad.

Comment: Which is consistent, since $\frac1i=-i$.

Comment: A final question. I've managed to get the series into the form 
$$
1/\pi -\frac{2}{\pi} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(2nx)+i\sin(2nx)}{2n^{2}-1},
$$, but I can't quite make the final step, assuming what I've done so far is correct.

Comment: The sum is over all $n\in\Bbb Z$, positive as well as negative and zero. This means that certain  terms will cancel. And you left out the contribution from $n=\pm1$